# Combining Navigo Pass with an SNCF point to point ticket outside Île-de-France

Tags: trains, tickets, france, paris, sncf

We will be travelling on an SNCF Intercités service from Paris. We both have Paris [Navigo](https://www.navigo.fr/) passes, one [weekly](https://www.transilien.com/fr/page-editoriale/navigo-semaine) pass and one [monthly](https://www.transilien.com/fr/page-editoriale/navigo-mois) pass, both of which will be valid on the day of travel. The service we will be taking departs from a central Paris station, which is in Navigo fare zone 1, to an SNCF station which is outside the Navigo fare zones (and therefore also outside the Île-de-France region), specifically Vernon-Giverny.

Is my understanding correct that as this journey is at the weekend and the journey is entirely within Île-de-France; the holder of the Monthly Navigo pass is entitled to travel the entirety of this journey without needing to purchase an additional ticket? **[*This question is incorrectly formulated and therefore does not require an answer anymore. Thanks to @jcaron for pointing this out.*]**

Secondly, **is it permitted for the holder of the Weekly Navigo pass to purchase a point to point ticket to get them between the last station within the Navigo fare zones and the final destination station?** Thus saving on purchasing a point to point ticket to cover the whole journey, a good proportion of which will be inside the Navigo fare zones.

Comment: Can you clarify what the destination station is? As far as I know, there are no longer any stations in the Île-de-France region which are not in Navigo zones since... 1991. Or do you mean a station served by an Île-de-France service but which is outside the region?

Comment: Also, the "standard" weekly and monthly Navigo passes cover all zones. The only exceptions are 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, but as you mention zone 1, you most certainly have a "all zones" passes, don't you?

Comment: @jcaron yes you are quite correct

Comment: The station is Vernon-Giverny, which I have just noticed is outside the IdF region. You are therefore again quite correct. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: If the Intercités train is direct, as some are, your only option is to buy the ticket from Paris to Vernon-Giverny. If the Intercités train stops in Mantes-La-Jolie, you could use your all-zones Navigo pass from Paris to Mantes-La-Jolie, and a Mantes-La-Jolie – Vernon-Giverny Intercités ticket for the remainder of the trip. You are however supposed to validate your pass, so at least on the way back to Paris it would probably not be very practical unless you want to visit the Mantes-La-Jolie train station :-)

Comment: @jcaron that's a good point. If however we were using e-tickets which do not require validation, this would become a non-issue? So as long as the service were a stopping service and our Intercités tickets were valid from/to the last stop in IdF fare zones then we'd be okay?

Comment: I was talking about the Navigo pass, I believe you are supposed to validate it any time you use it. Not sure if/how much this is actually enforced on such trains. Also, I’m actually wondering if you can use Navigo on Intercités trains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigo passes are valid on all trains that don't have compulsory reservation, regardless of whether the train is a *Transilien* (Île-de-France regional train), *TER* (regional train from another region), or *Intercités* (cross-region train). So that part isn't a problem. The problem is that the Navigo pass is only valid within Île-de-France. Even on a *Transilien*, the Navigo pass isn't valid for journeys outside the administrative boundaries of Île-de-France. Rail maps indicate the boundaries, for example on the [official Transilien map](https://www.transilien.com/sites/default/files/atoms/files/plan_general_du_reseau_francilien.pdf) the outside part with a dark background is outside Île-de-France (“*Tarification hors Île-de-France*” means “fare outside Île-de-France”).

In France, in most cases, you need a single fare for your complete journey. You can't combine different tickets or passes at a border between zones. There are a few exceptions, but they don't apply here: a Navigo pass can't be combined with a point-to-point ticket¹.

If you're going from A to C with a change of trains at B, then of course you can use a ticket or pass from A to B and a different ticket or pass from B to C. But you need to validate the second ticket at B. If you take a train from A to C and the train calls at B, you can still do this, but in principle you need to get off the train. In practice, I doubt that ticket collectors would enforce the rule so zealously, you can stay on the train if you don't need to validate anything at B.

For your trip out from Paris to Vernon, almost all trains call at Mantes, and reservations are not compulsory. So you can use your Navigo pass from Paris to Mantes, and get a ticket from Mantes to Vernon. If you get a paper ticket, you'll need to stamp it in Mantes: if you stamp it in Paris and your ticket is checked at Mantes, there's a serious risk that you'll get a fine because your ticket isn't valid. On the other hand, with a smartphone ticket, there's nothing to validate. So if you get a smartphone ticket for the Mantes–Vernon part, you're good.

For the trip back from Vernon to Paris, in principle, you need to validate your Navigo pass in Mantes. The pass stores the location and time of last validation. However, [the fine is 5€ if you pay on the spot](https://www.ratp.fr/categorie-faq/4761), and that's less than the fare difference between Vernon–Paris and Vernon–Mantes. Furthermore, in my experience, ticket checkers in SNCF mainline trains don't check the location of last validation (I'm not even sure if their machine shows this information).

So get the Mantes↔Vernon tickets on a smartphone and you're good. (Assuming your train does call at Mantes.)

---

Part of your question reflects obsolete or incorrect information about Navigo passes. Unfortunately many websites, even some official ones, aren't up-to-date.

Since 2015, all Navigo passes cover the whole Île-de-France region, except for two-zone passes that don't include Paris. So if you're based in Paris, zone-free days aren't relevant.

There used to be extension tickets for Navigo pass holders, priced at the fare from the last station within the zone of validity to the destination station (when starting from within the zone of validity; or symmetrically in the other direction). These tickets no longer exist since the 2015 rate changes that caused almost all passes to be valid for the whole region in the first place. And anyway extension tickets were only ever valid within Île-de-France, never for journeys extending past the regional border.

¹  <sub>It's possible to combine a Navigo pass with some main line *passes* that run up to the first station within the Navigo area, but those are monthly or yearly passes priced for commuters who do a return journey every weekday.</sub>

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much. I think we'll take the risk of getting the fine especially given that it's less than the fare difference anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I missread your question, your assumption is not correct. See below

For the first question, your assumption is not correct : weekends are "unzoned periods" where your 2-zones Navigo Pass can be used for any zones within the Navigo zones. Other "unzoned periods" include bank holidays, school holidays for Ile-de-France and during the summer (mid July to mid August). [Source](http://www.navigo.fr/titres/le-forfait-navigo-mois-presentation/). **NOTE**: this is **only valable for the monthly pass**, this **doesn't apply to weekly pass**.

**EDIT : this doesn't allow you to use the pass for any destination outside the Navigo fare zones, the unzoning is only relevant for the 2-zones pass you can buy (by opposition to the all-zones pass)**

For the second question, nothing prevents you from doing this and you will save money applying this scheme. Just make sure you have enough time to get the new ticket as some destinations are crowded and you might wait up to 10 mins before being able to purchase a ticket. This is called "Complément de parcours" [Source](http://www.navigo.fr/le-complement-de-parcours/)

Comment: Mmmm.... i was under the impression that « complements de parcours » no longer existed. The Navigo / Idf Mobilités / RATP / SNCF sites are sadly often not in sync with the current fare rules. Can’t check right now though.

Comment: @jcaron I confirm that *compléments de parcours* no longer exist. They went away with the introduction of Navigo Jour in 2018. But even Wikipédia hasn't been updated in all this time!